# How to search for specific text file which includes a string within the name and load data into richtextbox

Tags: c#

How can I search for a specific text file which contains a string and then load that string into a richtextbox. Below is an example

```
String name = "test";

string directory = @"C:\Users\"
```

// search for file within directory which contains string name and then load data from text file onto the rich text box.

Comment: That you found a solution within 10 minutes of posting this I think demonstrates part of the reason why there's an [expectation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that at least some attempt at researching the problem be made _before_ asking the question.  Further, that's great that you found the answer, but if you're not going to [share it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the community I think that makes this question not so useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should found files. After than, you can read all file one by one and append content in to RichTextBox. I hope this helps you

```
string name = "test";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users")
                          .Where(s => s.Contains(name))
                          .ToArray();

RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(file);

    richTextBox.AppendText(content);
}
```

Comment: I am glad for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have found a solution, but it might be useful anyway.

This code will return the content of the first `.txt` file in the specified path that contains the searched pattern - if any - and add the file content to a control (a `RichTextBox` in this case) text.

```
string FilePath = @"[DirectoryPath]";
string SearchPattern = "[TextToSearch]";

DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);

richTextBox1.Text = dInfo.GetFiles("*.txt").Select(finfo => {
    string FileText = File.ReadAllText(finfo.FullName);
    if (FileText.Contains(SearchPattern))
        return FileText;
    return string.Empty;
    }).Where(s => s != string.Empty).FirstOrDefault();
```